# Recursive Function to create Treeview for Angular.Treeview

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, treeview, apache-commons-io

I'm trying to come up with a recursive function that I can use to create the tree view structure that angular tree view uses.

Here's a link that shows the structure: https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview

I'm trying to create a tree view based on a file directory on the server and wanted to pass it back from the Java code with JSON. I'm struggling mostly with creating the function that will loop through the directory and create the necessary structure with children.

I've created a POJO class to reflect the tree view structure server side. I was trying to use the following function as a basis for this one:

```
private static void listFiles(File rootDir, String[] files){
    for (String fileName: files){
        File fileOrDir = new File(rootDir, fileName); 
        if (fileOrDir.isDirectory()){
            listFiles(fileOrDir, fileOrDir.list());
        } else {
            System.out.println(fileOrDir); 
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a clip of what the object looks like:

```
public class AngularTreeview {
private String label; 
private String id; 
private Collection<AngularTreeview> children;
}
```

An suggestions on the function would be awesome. Also alternatives on how to browse the file system on the server or easier ways to create the tree view structure is good to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int level = 0;

private static void listFiles(File rootDir, String[] files){

    String name = rootDir.toString();       
    System.out.println(name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1));

    for (String fileName: files){
        File fileOrDir = new File(rootDir, fileName); 
        if (fileOrDir.isDirectory()){   

            level += 1;
            for(int i = 0; i < level; ++i)
                System.out.print('*');          

            listFiles(fileOrDir, fileOrDir.list());
            level -= 1;         
        } else {            
            for(int i = 0; i <= level; ++i)
                System.out.print('*');
            System.out.println(fileOrDir); 
        }           
    }   

}
```

you can use other way to keep track of level and replace ('*') by your needed spaces or '\t'.

```
    File root = new File("C:\\Root");
    String[] files = root.list();
    listFiles(root, files);
```

output for your example :

Root
*admin
**C:\Root\admin\subAdmin1.txt
**subAdmin2
***subAdmin2-1
****C:\Root\admin\subAdmin2\subAdmin2-1\subAdmin2-1-1.txt
****C:\Root\admin\subAdmin2\subAdmin2-1\subAdmin2-1-2.txt
*guest
**C:\Root\guest\subguest1.txt
**subguest2
*user
**C:\Root\user\superuser1.txt
**superUser2

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up going with, I'm still working out using the results with angular treeview but I'll post that when it works.

```
public AngularTreeview getDirectoryTreeview(){
    File node = new File("C:\\[yourlocation]");     
    String[] subNote = node.list();

    AngularTreeview treeview = new AngularTreeview(node.getName());
    treeview.setChildren(setChildrenFunction(node, subNote));

    return treeview; 
}

public Collection<AngularTreeview> setChildrenFunction(File rootDir, String[] subfiles) {
    Collection<AngularTreeview> treecol = new ArrayList<AngularTreeview>(); 

    for (String fileName : subfiles){

        AngularTreeview child = new AngularTreeview(fileName);
        File fileOrDir = new File(rootDir, fileName); 
        if (fileOrDir.isDirectory()){
            child.setChildren(setChildrenFunction(fileOrDir, fileOrDir.list()));
        }

        treecol.add(child); 
    } 
    return treecol; 
}
```